# Lua Tables w/ Changing Variables - Mental Block

Tags: lua

I always assumed that changing the value of `k` from `"x"` to `20` would eliminate `"x"`. So why then in this example are we able to go back and reference `"x"`?

```
a = {}
k = "x"
a[k] = 10
print(a[k])        ---> Returns 10
print(a["x"])      ---> Returns 10
a[20] = "great"
k = 20
print(a[k])        ---> "great"
a["x"] = a["x"] + 1
print(a["x"])    --> 11
```

Why does that last print command work, and return `11`? I thought we set `k` = `20`. Why is `"x"` even in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua calls table what others programming languages call dictionary or hash, a table is a data structure that stores a pairs of key and value, we can not have two identical keys in a table, but we can have same values for diferent keys. So basicly what you are doing in line 2 is giving your variable "k" value "x", on line 3 you are saying that the table "a" will have an entry with value 10 which is referenced by key "x" not variable "k", variable "k" is a anddress not a value.

I hope I helped somehow.

Comment: That helped a lot - so, `a[k] = 10` is mainly a naming convention. You're telling the program, "I want to place a value in table `a`, `10`. And I want to reference that value with a key. In this case, I want my key to be whatever value is attached to variable `k`. In other words, I want a spot in table `a` indexed by the value of variable `k`, *at that point in time*. It only matters in the moment.

Comment: @bottles: That's how the vast majority of programming languages with variables work. They only look at the *value* of the variable at the time they are used. Changing a variable after it has been used will not retroactively affect prior actions.